# Splicing or Extending 2.5mm2 Twin & Earth (UK)

Tags: electrical, wiring, uk, smart-switch

I am trying to install a WiFi connected smart switch to control a ceiling light. The wall box is too shallow to accommodate this, so I need to install it inline.
To do this, I need to move the circuit so I can place the smart switch in an accessible location for maintenance

What approved methods could I use to splice and extend this wire? 
Using a junction box seems the obvious choice, but I'm wondering what else I could use.

Comment: Generally you're not allowed to bury splices in walls, so you could wind up with a junction box with a blank cover.  Do they not make deeper junction boxes, or junction box extensions, in the UK?  The US has a thing called "surface conduit" where you start off an embedded junction box. This "starter box" sticks out an inch from the wall so the conduit can dock up.  Using the box alone (without any conduit) is an easy way to deepen a box.

Comment: We have pattress extenders which are intended for this situation (they don't join on to surface conduit/minitrunking). Schneide are available in 10mm and 19mm and work with round-corner accessories; BG available in 10mm and work with square-corner accessories. https://www.comtecdirect.co.uk/product/schneider-backbox-extension-collars/PG0345 https://www.electricaldirect.co.uk/product/bg-1-gang-10mm-square-spacer-white-751298?vat=1